# POST request with C++ curl

Tags: c++, libcurl

I try POST JSON on my Server, but it doesn't work. When I do post server is empty and doesn't have a file.

How do POST correctly?

```
CURL *curl;
    string data;
    CURLcode res;
    std::ifstream myfile;
    myfile.open("test_4.json");
    string content( (istreambuf_iterator<char>(myfile) ),
                  (istreambuf_iterator<char>()    ) );
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    string l="filedata=";
    if(curl) {

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "my_server");

    
     curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, l+content);

 
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
 
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
  }
```

also I have code on python which works

pp=requests.post("my_server",data={"filedata":response})

js code of POST on my server (I can't change)

```
app.post("/api/arch_base",jsonParser,function(req,res){
    
    if(!req.body) return res.sendStatus(400);
    
    const fdata=req.body.filedata;
    
    console.log(fdata);
    
     const collection = req.app.locals.collection;
    
    collection.find({}).toArray(function(err,arch_data){
         if(err) return console.log(err);
         
         if(arch_data.length>0)
         {
             let id=arch_data[0]._id;
             
             collection.findOneAndUpdate({_id:id},{$set: {FileData:fdata}},{returnOriginal:false},function(err,result){
                 
                  if(err) return console.log(err);
             });
         }
         
        
      });
    
    
    haveUpdates=true;
    
    
});
```

Comment: What is your proof that `myfile.open("test_4.json");` actually succeeds in opening the file? What is your proof that the POST URL is correct?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik file succeeds in opening and url correct, mayby I use wrong flag CURLOPT_POSTFIELD?

Comment: How did you conclude that "file succeeds in opening"? There's nothing in the shown code that actually proves that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

libcurl is c, not c++. It expects `char*`, not `std::string`.

Also from https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS.html:

> The data pointed to is NOT copied by the library: as a consequence, it
> must be preserved by the calling application until the associated
> transfer finishes. This behavior can be changed (so libcurl does copy the data) by setting the CURLOPT_COPYPOSTFIELDS option.

You also need to set CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE as CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS only provides a pointer.

Also, I'm sure you're getting "filedata=<file>", not "data={filedata:<file>}". You might want a json-library (e.g. jsoncpp) to make sure you get valid json.